# How do I update elements in a list, in a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to update values within a list, each iteration. I am not sure if this is the best approach. I know about string accumulators, int / float accumulators.

The values that I want to update is:

- Minimum monthly payment
- Principle Paid
- and Remaining Balance

I want to update the values with the updated calculations that are done in the for loop.

**More details on the problem.**

Write a program to calculate the credit card balance after one year if a person only pays the minimum monthly payment required by the credit card company each month.

Use raw_input() to ask for the following three floating point numbers:
1. the outstanding balance on the credit card
2. annual interest rate
3. minimum monthly payment rate

For each month, print the minimum monthly payment, remaining balance, principle paid in the
format shown in the test cases below. All numbers should be rounded to the nearest penny.
Finally, print the result, which should include the total amount paid that year and the remaining
balance.

[4800.0, 0.18, 0.02]
**The output is like this:**

Month: 1
Minimum payment: 96.0
Principle paid: 24.0
Remaining Balance: 4776.0

Month: 2

Month: 3

```
store_val_list = list()

outstanding_balance = float(raw_input('Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: '))
store_val_list.append(outstanding_balance)
annual_interest_rate = float(raw_input('Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: '))
store_val_list.append(annual_interest_rate)
minimum_monthly_payment_rate = float(raw_input('Enter the minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: '))
store_val_list.append(minimum_monthly_payment_rate)

print(store_val_list)


def pay_minimum(val_list):
    calc_store_list = list()
    for month in range(1, 13):
        print('Month:', month)

        if month == 1:
            # 1. Minimum monthly payment (Minimum monthly payment rate X Balance)
            min_payment = val_list[2] * val_list[0]
            calc_store_list.append(min_payment)
            print('Minimum payment:', min_payment)

            # 1.5. Interest Paid (Annual interest rate / 12 months X Balance)

            interest_paid = val_list[1] / 12 * val_list[0]
            calc_store_list.append(interest_paid)
            # print('Interest paid:', interest_paid)

            # 2. Principle Paid (Minimum monthly payment - Interest Paid)

            principle_paid = min_payment - interest_paid
            calc_store_list.append(principle_paid)
            print('Principle paid:', round(principle_paid))

            # 3. Remaining Balance (Balance - Principal paid)

            remaining_balance = val_list[0] - principle_paid
            calc_store_list.append(remaining_balance)
            print('Remaining Balance:', remaining_balance, '\n')
            continue
```

I am using lists because it's easier to calculate the indexes of the list, than single variables.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your question is. What values do you want to update, and with what do you want to update them with?

Comment: Okay, I updated my question. My problem is quite long, so I put only a portion of the problem in the question.

Comment: I may be missing something in the question, presumably you want to update the `val_list` argument to the function, but what prevents you from using array (list) sub-scripts (indecies) as you have already?  For example, 
`l = [x for x in range(1, 5)]`
`for i in range(4):      l[i] = l[i]**2`

Comment: I am a beginner at Python. array(list) sub-scripts is something to keep in mind. I am finding out how to use this.

Comment: I am going to use multiple variables, and update those variables with the accumulator patterns that I have learned.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out an approach.